# Working with other's pull request

Tags: github, pull-request

My team mate has made a pull request in Github to a repo in which I'm a member.  We have few changes requested to be done. Now I want to make these changes. What is the right way to work on this pull request.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should clarify your scenario a bit more. Currently your question is very vague. Do you own the repo to which the PR has been made or are you and your team contributing to somebody else's repo?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the pull request in question is on branch `pull-request`, work on the changes like so:

```
# Fetch and checkout pull-request
$ git fetch origin pull-request
$ git checkout -B pull-request origin/pull-request

# Make changes and commit
$ touch file
$ git commit -am "I touched a file!"

# Push your changes
$ git push origin pull-request
```